# How to create dynamic duration calculation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am building a project status dashboard in Power BI. Each project has different phases, together with start date and end date.

I had also built a date dimension and defined workdays as well.

I am using Gantt Chart By MAQ Software to show the schedule for all projects in a hierarchy manner. And I want to use a Card visualization to show the dynamic durations no matter which project and which phase I select in the Gantt Chart.

This is my current measure:

```
Duration(Weeks) =
DIVIDE (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Calender,
            AND (
                AND (
                    Calender[FullDateAlternateKey] >= MIN ( PlannedSchedule[Start Date] ),
                    Calender[FullDateAlternateKey] <= MAX ( PlannedSchedule[End Date] )
                ),
                Calender[IsWorkDay] = "Y"
            )
        )
    ),
    5
)
```

It does not change as I select different processes or phases, but it changes if I use slicer instead.

Anyone can help on this?

Comment: Do your table relationships allow filtering in both directions and do you have cross-filtering interactions enabled for the visuals?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Yes, I do have these capabilities you mentioned.